# RODBC channel error in global environnement

Tags: r, postgresql, postgresql-9.5, rodbc

I've set up a connection between R and SQL using the package RODBC and managed to connect and query the database from R.

I've created a small R function which objective is to delete some lines (as parameter) in a specific table.

Here it is (nameDB is the name of my database, and values_conversion another function I did to convert some data from R format to SQL format) :

```
delete_SQL = function(data, table){
  ch = odbcConnect(nameDB,"postgres")
  names = sqlColumns(channel=ch,table,schema="public",catalog = nameDB)$COLUMN_NAME
  for(i in 1:nrow(data)){
    sqlQuery(channel=ch,query=paste0("DELETE FROM public.\"",table,"\" WHERE ",
                       paste0(names," = ",values_conversion(data[i,]),collapse = " and "),";"),errors = TRUE)
  }
  odbcCloseAll()
}
```

Query exemple : "DELETE FROM public.\"lieu_protection\" WHERE lieu_id = 3 and protection_id = 1430;"

The code inside this function works fine when I execute everything directly, but when I call the function it throws an

```
Error in sqlQuery(channel = ch, query = paste0("DELETE FROM public.\"",  : 
  first argument is not an open RODBC channel
```

I have a similar function that's getting and returning data from SQL and which is working fine, so I guess it has something to do with the delete, but the error is about the channel, so I'm quite confused.

Thanks to anyone that can help !

Comment: Which type of SQL server are you using?
Also, Please do not create SQL queries by joining strings together. You should always use parametrised queries, otherwise you have a significant security risk from SQL injection.

Comment: It's a local PostgreSQL 9.5 server, it's just for tests right now so security doesn't really matter but I'll keep this in mind before I deploy anything.

Comment: It's still a bad habit, that may eventually creep into production code,